# Delete all files created before todays date from AMAZON S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I know below provided code is for deleting files from AMAZON s3 bucket, But my requirement is to delete all files created before today's date from the bucket. That means, I want to pass today's date,bucketName as a input parameters to the function and that function should delete all the files created before today's date from that bucket.how i can achieve that.

```
String Bucket_Name = "my_bucket";
String key = "Path/to/my/folder";   
ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(BUCKET_NAME, key);
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) 
        {
        s3Client.deleteObject(BUCKET_NAME, objectSummary.getKey());
        }
```

Comment: Depending on what you're really trying to accomplish, S3 can do this for you [automatically](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the date to the time the object was last modified, that's the only information you can get about dates from [S3ObjectSummary](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html).

It's stored as part of the metadata of the object, like it's explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html).

```
String Bucket_Name = "my_bucket";
String key = "Path/to/my/folder";
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();  
ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(BUCKET_NAME, key);
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) 
{
    if(objectSummary.getLastModified().before(today))
       s3Client.deleteObject(BUCKET_NAME, objectSummary.getKey());
}
```

Comment: This may not always return the entire list of objects. You may need to use ObjectListing.isTruncated() method to see if the returned listing is complete or if additional listObjects calls are needed to get more results. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-